# Rendering Custom Customer Attribute issue

Tags: magento-1, customer-attribute, render

This is my code:

```
$attributeCode = 'customer_custom_field';
$attributeData = array(
    'label'         => 'Customer Custom Field',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined'  => 1,
    'backend'            => 'mynamespace_mymodule/attribute',
    'input_renderer'     => 'mynamespace_mymodule/customer_attribute'
);
```

and in the mynamespace/mymodule/Block/Customer/Attribute.php file I have:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Customer_Attribute extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function getAfterElementHtml()
    {
        echo 1; exit();
        $html = parent::getAfterElementHtml();
        return $html."  <script>
                        $('".$this->getHtmlId()."').disable();
                        </script>";
    }

}
```

I never get the echo 1; exit (). Why ? The "input_renderer"
 is not available for customer attributes ? thx

**[UPDATE]**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Mymodule>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
        </Mynamespace_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: please share config.xml cod of your module

Comment: should I had to include smth specific , customer attribute related there in the config.xml ? Cuz I didn't

Comment: please share code of  `mynamespace/mymodule/etc/config.xml`

Comment: @AmitBera I updated my post , please check  it